# Pandas: for loop weirdness

Tags: python, pandas

I'm completely baffled by the below snippets. I expected both to give me the same output, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the `train_test_split` call is missing in the top snippet?

Comment: that's an irrelevant artifact of the screenshot, apologies

Comment: Don't post screenshots, post text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the top snippet is returning the length of the entire dataframe.

Consider :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"A":[1, 1, 0, 0, 1]})
print(len(df["A"]==1))
```

Output : `5`

Comment: `df["A"]==1` returns a series of booleans, it doesn't filter the df.

Comment: I think you have to write `df[df["A"] == 1]` to filter it.

Comment: You are correct - `len(df[df["A"]==1])` would return `3`